# Wordpress payment Error

Tags: wordpress, ssl, paypal

I have a wordpress tourist website.I am using citytour theme.In the website when ever a user books a tour then he fills the form,after that the `paypal` page should appear but instead it shows this error :

> SetExpressCheckout failed: error:14077410:SSL routines:SSL23_GET_SERVER_HELLO:sslv3 alert handshake failure(35)

How can I solve this error and direct my user to the paypal page once he fills in the form ?

Answer (score 1):

Your server software stack needs to be updated.  Take a look at [this info](https://www.angelleye.com/paypal-ssl-error-poodle-vunerability/) for more details about what's going on.